# Could not write merged data into yml file

Tags: perl

I am trying to merge two yml files with following `perl` code.  When I print the `$res` via `Dumper` module, I could see the data.

I ran my script, but `final.yml` has reference data, instead of original data:-

```
srcARRAY(0x1013320)local_pointerARRAY(0x10228f8)
```

Code:-

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump;
use Data::Dumper;
use Storable qw(dclone);
use YAML qw(LoadFile);
use File::Slurp qw(write_file);
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);
Hash::Merge::set_behavior('RETAINMENT_PRECEDENT');

die "Usage: $0 file1 file2\n" if @ARGV != 2;
my ($fname1, $fname2) = @ARGV;

my $yml1 = LoadFile($fname1);
my $yml2 = LoadFile($fname2);


my $res = merge($yml1, $yml2);
#print Dumper $res;
write_file("final.yml", { binmode => ':raw' }, %{$res});
```

Should we need to set any custom settings in perl `Hash::Merge` module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write the YAML data out to a file, use the [YAML](https://metacpan.org/dist/YAML/view/lib/YAML.pod) `Dump` function:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use YAML qw(LoadFile Dump);
use File::Slurp qw(write_file);
use Hash::Merge qw(merge);
Hash::Merge::set_behavior('RETAINMENT_PRECEDENT');

die "Usage: $0 file1 file2\n" if @ARGV != 2;
my ($fname1, $fname2) = @ARGV;

my $yml1 = LoadFile($fname1);
my $yml2 = LoadFile($fname2);

my $res = merge($yml1, $yml2);
write_file("final.yml", Dump($res));
```

Or, you can also use `YAML::DumpFile` instead of `File::Slurp::write_file`:

```
DumpFile("final.yml", $res);
```